# JSTL forEach use variable in javacode

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl

I want to use the actual item from my `c:forEach` in a `<% JavaCode/JSPCode %>`.
How do I access to this item?

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${list}">
   <% MyProduct p = (MyProduct) ${item}; %>   <--- ???
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use scriptlets (ie. the stuff in between the `<% %>` tags. It's considered bad practice because it encourages putting too much code, even business logic, in a view context. Instead, stick to JSTL and EL expressions exclusively. Try this:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${list}">
    <c:set var="p" value="${item}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 19):

Anything that goes inside `<% %>` has to be valid Java, and `${item}` isn't. The `${...}` is JSP EL syntax.

You can do it like this:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${list}">
   <% MyProduct p = (MyProduct) pageContext.getAttribute("item"); %>   
</c:forEach>
```

However, this is a horrible way to write JSPs. Why do you want to use scriptlets, when you're already using JSTL/EL?  Obviously you're putting something inside that `<forEach>`, and whatever it is, you should be able to do without using a scriptlet.